# Implicit lifting in scala

Tags: scala, implicits

I want to implicitly convert functions from `A => B` to `List[A] => List[B]`.

I wrote the following implicit definition:

```
implicit def lift[A, B](f: A => B): List[A] => List[B] = ...
```

Unfortunately, when I write the following code, implicit aren't applied:

```
val plusOne: (List[Int]) => List[Int] = (x: Int) => (x + 1)
```

If I annotate the function with explicit time, it works fine.

Why? How can I fix it?

UPDATE. It seems that the problem is specific to anonymous functions. Compare:

```
@Test
def localLiftingGenerics {
  implicit def anyPairToList[X, Y](x: (X, Y)): List[X] => List[Y] = throw new UnsupportedOperationException  

  val v: List[String] => List[Int] = ("abc", 239)
}

@Test
def localLiftingFuns {
  implicit def fun2ListFun[X, Y](f: X => Y): List[X] => List[Y] = throw new UnsupportedOperationException

  val v: List[String] => List[Int] = ((x: String) => x.length)
}
```

The first one is compiled well. The second one is marked as error

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to implement the `implicit def`?

Comment: @ChrisJamesC Updated with a test case

Comment: Are you sure you need/want to do this? `map` buys a lot of clarity for a few characters, and e.g. `val plusOne: (List[Int]) => List[Int] = _ map (_ + 1)` is actually shorter than your version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) / Expressions / Anonymous Functions (6.23):

> If the expected type of the anonymous function is of the form
>   scala.Function*n*[*S<sub>1</sub>, …, S<sub>n</sub>, R*], the expected type of *e* is *R* ...

So, the result type of the function will be inferred as `List[Int]` unless you separate the function definition from the function value assignment (to get rid of the expected type):

```
val function = (x: Int) => (x + 1)
val plusOne: (List[Int]) => List[Int] = function
```

or specify the function type explicitly:

```
val plusOne: (List[Int]) => List[Int] = ((x: Int) => (x + 1)): Int => Int
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Scala 2.9.1-1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_05)</sub>

**A first observation:** If you duplicate `fun2ListFun` and rename it to, e.g.,``fun2ListFun, you'll get

```
found   : String => <error>
 required: List[String] => List[Int]

Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method fun2ListFun2 of type [X, Y](f: X => Y)List[X] => List[Y]
 and method fun2ListFun of type [X, Y](f: X => Y)List[X] => List[Y]
 are possible conversion functions from String => <error> to List[String] => List[Int]
  val v: List[String] => List[Int] = ((x: String) => x.length)
```

It looks as if the compiler considers both implicits as applicable.

**A second observation:**

Splitting

```
val v: List[String] => List[Int] = ((x: String) => x.length) /* Error*/
```

into

```
val f = ((x: String) => x.length)
val v: List[String] => List[Int] = f /* Works */
```

makes the compiler happy.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit conversion for the input value compiles. So we just have a problem for the output of the anonymous function

```
 def localLiftingFuns {
   implicit def fun2ListFun[X, Y](f: X => Y): List[X] => Y = throw new UnsupportedOperationException

   val v: List[String] => Int = ((x: String) => x.length)
 }
```

A possible fix using a second implicit conversion:

```
 def localLiftingFuns {
   implicit def fun2ListFun[X, Y](f: X => List[Y]): List[X] => List[Y] = throw new UnsupportedOperationException
   implicit def type2ListType[X](x:X): List[X] = throw new UnsupportedOperationException

   val v: List[String] => List[Int] = ((x: String) => x.length)
 }
```

This version compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the compiler has hard time figuring what is going on with the type of the function. If you will give him a little help, it would work:

```
scala> implicit def lift[A,B](f: A => B) = (_:List[A]).map(f)
lift: [A, B](f: (A) => B)(List[A]) => List[B]

scala> val f: List[Int] => List[Int] = ((_:Int) + 1):(Int => Int)
f: (List[Int]) => List[Int] = <function1>
```